# How to print a string based on the postion in c?

Tags: c, string, file, tokenize

I am working on a question which requires me to print a string given a `field-number` at that position. The strings should be read from a file.

`file.txt`

```
C is a language.
lex lexical analyser
(blank line)
      gcc is good
```

If the `field-number` is 2 (i.e the second word in the sentence). The program should output

```
is
lexical
(NULL)
is
```

I wrote a function but don't think its the correct way and that it would work for all cases. It should handle extra blanks or newlines.

```
while (fgets(buffer, MAX, file) != NULL) {
    for (int i = 1; i < strlen(buffer); i++) {
        if (count == field_number - 1) {
            int j = i;
            while (j < strlen(buffer) && buffer[j] != ' ') {
                printf("%c", buffer[j++]);
            }
            printf("\n");
            count = 0;
            break;
        }

        if (buffer[i] == ' ' && buffer[i - 1] != ' ') {
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

I am a beginner. This code should be easy to understand.

Comment: you are doing the tokenizing on your own, although the language already provides one: have a look at `strtok`.

Comment: Yes, but I have to write my own logic from scratch here.

Comment: because of the last `if` statement. otherwise `[i-1]` would be -1, leading to an error. not very good

Comment: yes, `sscanf` could be used. Can you show how?

Comment: How can I use `sscanf` since I don't know how many words are there.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for all the cases,

```
int main() {
    //FILE* file = fopen(__FILE__, "r");
    //int field_number = 2;

    int new_line = 0; // var to keep track of new line came or not
    int word = 0;
    int count = 0;
    char c, prev_c;
    while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
        // printf("[%c]", c);
        // if a new line char comes it means you entered a new line
        if(c == '\n') {
            // you have to print the new line here on the output to handle
            // empty line cases
            printf("\n");
            new_line = 1; // when line changes
            word = 0; // no word has come in this new line so far
            count = 0;    // count becomes 0
        } else if( c == ' ' && prev_c != ' ') {
            if(word)
                count++;
            if(count == field_number) // if count exceeds field_number
                new_line = 0; // wait till next line comes
        } else if (new_line && count == field_number - 1) {
            printf("%c", c);
        } else {
            word = 1; // fi a not new line or non space char comes, a word has come
        }
        prev_c = c;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why `count == field_number` is used?

Comment: When `count == field_number`,  you have already printed the word and now you should wait until you go to the next line. Then you can start counting the words and print the word which is the word `field_number` tells you to print.

Comment: This is not printing the expected output.